# Is homestead a hard fork and when will it be activated?

Tags: homestead, hardforks

In one of the descriptions it was mentioned that the homestead update contains a new opcode and other changes [that are not backward compatible](https://ethereum-homestead.readthedocs.org/en/latest/introduction/the-homestead-release.html). Thus a hardfork will be required. What is a process of switching to the new consensus rules? Is it a given block or something dynamic (e.g. as soon as 75% of the miners are signaling support by some meta information in the block)

Answer (score 4):

Homestead will begin at block 1,150,000 which will happen at midday on [pi day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi_Day).

Switching to homestead can be done by updating your ethereum client to a version which contains the homestead changes.

- [geth 1.3.5](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/releases/tag/v1.3.5)
- [cpp-ethereum 1.2.1](https://github.com/ethereum/webthree-umbrella/releases/tag/v1.2.1)
- [parity 0.9.1](https://github.com/ethcore/parity/releases/tag/beta-0.9.1)