# Can a child block have an earlier timestamp than the parent block?

Tags: mining, timestamp

From From [EIP 2](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-2.mediawiki), the Homestead difficulty adjustment algorithm is:

> ```
>     block_diff = parent_diff + parent_diff // 2048 * 
>       max(1 - (block_timestamp - parent_timestamp) // 10, -99) + 
>       int(2**((block.number // 100000) - 2))
> ```
>
> where // is the integer division operator, eg. 6 // 2 = 3, 7 // 2 = 3, 8 // 2 = 4.

Due to differences in the clock settings on different miner's computers, can `block_timestamp` be before `parent_timestamp`?

<strike>And if `block_timestamp` CANNOT be before `parent_timestamp`, how are differences in the clock settings on different miner's computers taken into account?</strike>

---

**EDIT June 12 2016** I've moved the second question above into [How do Ethereum mining nodes maintain a time consistent with the network?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5924/how-do-ethereum-mining-nodes-maintain-a-time-consistent-with-the-network)

This question was prompted by the question [How does the Ethereum Homestead difficulty adjustment algorithm work?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5913/how-does-the-ethereum-homestead-difficulty-adjustment-algorithm-work), which was prompted by the question [What was the first block mined with Homestead?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5901/what-was-the-first-block-mined-with-homestead)

---

Other related Q&As:

- [How is the Mining Difficulty calculated on Ethereum?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1880/how-is-the-mining-difficulty-calculated-on-ethereum/1910#1910)
- [What is the measured distribution of block times since Homestead?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5879/what-is-the-measured-distribution-of-block-times-since-homestead)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**block_timestamp CANNOT be before parent_timestamp**

This is enforced by the protocol, see [yellow paper](http://gavwood.com/paper.pdf):

> Hs is the timestamp of block H and **must fulfil** the relation: (48) Hs >
>   P(H)Hs

Also in my [empirical research on Homesteads blocktimes](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/5905/264) there was not a single negative value.

Comment: Out of interest, was there any 0 values?

Comment: No zeros, but a substantial amount of 1s times

Comment: Note that the protocol has no other restrictions on timestamps; some game theory is what prevents timestamps from being far out in the future: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5927/how-would-a-miner-cope-with-a-huge-block-time

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned, the protocol prevents this from happening.

As for miners' clocks, the protocol can't tell what their actual clock says. A miner could simply lie, put a different timestamp in, and the protocol would be none-the-wiser. The protocol *attempts* to prevent this by the difficulty adjustment formula.

To quote the Yellow Paper:

> This mechanism enforces a homeostasis in terms of the
>   time between blocks; a smaller period between the last two
>   blocks results in an increase in the difficulty level and thus
>   additional computation required, lengthening the likely
>   next period. Conversely, if the period is too large, the
>   difficulty, and expected time to the next block, is reduced.

The Homestead difficulty formula change was to address the very issue of miners reporting wrong timestamps.