# How do Ethereum mining nodes maintain a time consistent with the network?

Tags: mining, nodes, network, timestamp

We have established that the timestamp on a parent block has to be before the timestamp of a child block in [Can a child block have an earlier timestamp than the parent block?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5915/can-a-child-block-have-an-earlier-timestamp-than-the-parent-block).

How are differences in the clock settings on different miners' computers taken into account?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Ethereum nodes (regardless of mining) need to have an accurate time, otherwise they will not be able to connect to peers and to the network (https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Connecting-to-the-network).

Small differences in time are tolerated by nodes, but as one node's time gets further away from Coordinated UTC Time (per [NTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol)), its number of peers will reduce and eventually it will have zero peers and be disconnected from the network.

**A miner M wants to have a time consistent with the network, so that other miners will build upon the blocks that M mines.**

Blocks must be within reasonable Unix time, otherwise miners are unlikely to build upon blocks with unreasonable timestamps.  ([Example](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/5932/42))

EDIT: For clarity, in Ethereum, the **only rule** about timestamps is that the **timestamp must be greater than the previous timestamp**.  There is **no other rule**: old docs such as the [white paper](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/White-Paper#blockchain-and-mining) and [wiki](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Block-Protocol-2.0#block-validation-algorithm) may mention 15 minutes (900 seconds), and here are the corrections:

[White paper](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/White-Paper#blockchain-and-mining):

> Check that the timestamp of the block is greater than that of the
>   referenced previous block <s>and less than 15 minutes into the future</s>

[wiki](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Block-Protocol-2.0#block-validation-algorithm):

> Is <s>block.timestamp <= now + 900 and is</s> block.timestamp **>**
>   parent.timestamp? (strictly greater)

Unfortunately, the outdated, wrong information has been picked up by others such as [here](http://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~loiluu/papers/oyente.pdf) and [here](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/1007.pdf).

The [Yellow paper](https://github.com/ethereum/yellowpaper) is the formal specification and see *Block Header Validity* (section 4.4.4, equation 48).

Comment: Yellow paper is the formal specification, but miner majority forms the practical specification developers have to live with. And as of 2020-02-13, Geth master branch considers anything further in the future than *15 seconds* a "future block" and thus ineligible for consensus. See https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/consensus/ethash/consensus.go#L45

Comment: @Jusso Thanks. Also taking this opportunity to highlight this important topic that needs more work https://ethresear.ch/t/network-adjusted-timestamps

Comment: @eth, why is there a need for checking if the header time is not too far from the parent  and why is there a need for NTP at all ? in the geth client , where the miner solves the block, we can put `time` in a `header` as UNIX time . Why does local time set on the computer matter ?

Comment: @NikaKurashvili Let me try asking it this way, if you're a miner and the previous block is timestamped 10 minutes or a day in the future, will you build on that block or ignore it? If you're a node and some other peer node keeps giving you blocks with future timestamps , do you want those blocks or will you ban that peer?

Answer (score 9):

Here's the code I've found so far that deals with syncing time. It uses `pool.ntp.org:123` as the time syncing source.

From [Go Ethereum - p2p/discover/ntp.go, lines 48-65](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/p2p/discover/ntp.go#L48-L65):

```
func checkClockDrift() {
    drift, err := sntpDrift(ntpChecks)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    if drift < -driftThreshold || drift > driftThreshold {
        warning := fmt.Sprintf("System clock seems off by %v, which can prevent network connectivity", drift)
        howtofix := fmt.Sprintf("Please enable network time synchronisation in system settings")
        separator := strings.Repeat("-", len(warning))

        glog.V(logger.Warn).Info(separator)
        glog.V(logger.Warn).Info(warning)
        glog.V(logger.Warn).Info(howtofix)
        glog.V(logger.Warn).Info(separator)
    } else {
        glog.V(logger.Debug).Infof("Sanity NTP check reported %v drift, all ok", drift)
    }
}
```

From [Go Ethereum - p2p/discover/ntp.go, lines 73-127](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/p2p/discover/ntp.go#L73-L127):

```
func sntpDrift(measurements int) (time.Duration, error) {
    // Resolve the address of the NTP server
    addr, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp", ntpPool+":123")
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    // Construct the time request (empty package with only 2 fields set):
    //   Bits 3-5: Protocol version, 3
    //   Bits 6-8: Mode of operation, client, 3
    request := make([]byte, 48)
    request[0] = 3<<3 | 3

    // Execute each of the measurements
    drifts := []time.Duration{}
    ...
    // Calculate average drif (drop two extremities to avoid outliers)
    sort.Sort(durationSlice(drifts))

    drift := time.Duration(0)
    for i := 1; i < len(drifts)-1; i++ {
        drift += drifts[i]
    }
    return drift / time.Duration(measurements), nil
}
```

[Go Ethereum - p2p/discover/ntp.go, lines 33-36](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/p2p/discover/ntp.go#L33-L36):

```
const (
    ntpPool   = "pool.ntp.org" // ntpPool is the NTP server to query for the current time
    ntpChecks = 3              // Number of measurements to do against the NTP server
)
```

And driftThreshold = 10 seconds from [p2p/discover/udp.go, line 57](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/p2p/discover/udp.go#L57)

If the hardcoded pool.ntp.org does undergo a long and sustained DDoS or DNS cache poisoning, Ethereum nodes will eventually fail to sync. But it will take a long time for the mining computers to drift by more than 10 seconds. And the Ethereum developers would have a a new fix out by that time.

Comment: In Geth master branch, allowed time drift is only 15 seconds into the future: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/consensus/ethash/consensus.go#L45

Answer (score 6):

**TL;DR: Blocks must be within reasonable Unix time or they will be rejected.**

The [yellow paper](http://gavwood.com/paper.pdf) states:

> timestamp: A scalar value equal to **the reasonable output of Unix’s
> time()** at this block’s inception; formally H<sub>s</sub>.

The [white paper](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/White-Paper) says:

> The basic block validation algorithm in Ethereum is as follows:
>
> - [...]
> - Check that the timestamp of the block is greater than that of the referenced previous block and **less than 15 minutes into the future**

Comment: Does this mean that if a miner with their computer time set say 1 hour in the future mines a block, all other miners will be unable to mine on top of that block?

Comment: good question :-) https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5927/how-would-a-miner-cope-with-a-huge-block-time

Comment: Is the <= 2 hour in the white paper referring to the bitcoin algorithm?

Comment: Yeah! need to fix that!

Comment: fixed it, pheew!

Comment: 1. I provided clarification on what "rejected" means since there's an element of game theory rather than outright rejection by the protocol.   2. "15 mins" part in the whitepaper is old and it may get removed from it.  The yellowpaper is the definitive source for the protocol.