# Using 'now' to check time in Solidity - safe from miner manipulation?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, timers

I am writing a contract where I am storing the date/time using 'now' and performing date/time checks on those stored values.

My questions is how do you prevent date/time manipulation from miners?

If it cannot be prevented how do contracts even use date/time for critical checks?

Comment: `now` is an alias for `block.timestamp`. As such, this question should cover it: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6795/is-block-timestamp-save-for-longer-time-periods

Comment: Ok, it looks like the block time stamp cannot go to far out of range otherwise the block can be rejected,