# How does CryptoKitties track time?

Tags: dapps, oracles, timestamp, timers

I'm looking at `KittyBreeding.sol` and see

```
 /// @dev Set the cooldownEndTime for the given Kitty, based on its current cooldownIndex.
    ///  Also increments the cooldownIndex (unless it has hit the cap).
    /// @param _kitten A reference to the Kitty in storage which needs its timer started.
    function _triggerCooldown(Kitty storage _kitten) internal {
        // Compute the end of the cooldown time (based on current cooldownIndex)
        _kitten.cooldownEndTime = uint64(now + cooldowns[_kitten.cooldownIndex]);
```

but I don't see where "now" is defined, except in their `kitty-core.test.js`

How does this DAPP track time, which lets the website show timers?

Comment: Where did you get the .sol file from?

Comment: https://github.com/axiomzen/cryptokitties-bounty/tree/master/contracts

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`now` is a Solidity [special variable](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html?highlight=timestamp#block-and-transaction-properties), which equates to the current time since the epoch, [in seconds](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7853/is-the-block-timestamp-value-in-solidity-seconds-or-milliseconds).

From the documentation (linked above):

> now (uint): current block timestamp (alias for block.timestamp)

Answer (score 4):

It's worth noting that miners can manipulate `now` and so it shouldn't be relied upon for anything sensitive such as seeding Psuedo-Random Number Generators.

Comment: So is tracking delta of block IDs a better way to track units of time?

Comment: Agree with Ismael's review but moderators need to be careful about affecting reputation, so even converting this into a comment might be interfering too much.  Will leave as is.

Comment: @quantumpotato It is more secure, as it's harder to game. Btw, [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/916xni/how_to_pwn_fomo3d_a_beginners_guide/)'s a real-world scenario where an on-chain Pseudo-Random Number Generator was implemented. It enabled a deterministic trapdoor.