# How to do a contract with expire time?

Tags: timestamp

I'm trying to do some modification to a test contract and i want to do it valid until a period of time like defining

```
startingTime= 25/08/2017;
endingTime= 27/08/2017;
```

is this possible in some way and what type should i use? i already checked the block.timestamp thing and don't like much that function because of the miners influence on that.

Comment: Use block number, that's how they do for metropolis release and so on

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer, any source or example about that release maybe?

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking at something happening days in advance you should probably stop worrying and just use `block.timestamp`. See this discussion on how much you should worry about miner manipulation: [Solidity: Timestamp dependency, is it possible to do safely?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15047/solidity-timestamp-dependency-is-it-possible-to-do-safely/15049)

If you're looking at an outcome within a few minutes, you should probably also require a minimum `block.number`, as `block.timestamp` is easily manipulated between blocks or over small numbers of blocks.

If you really need more confidence and/or precision than that, an alternative is to use some external timestamping service, but obviously that brings its own trust and security issues.

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer, i know what you are saying, only want to know if is there some other way to control this type of cases