# How reliable is it to use Block number to calculate Time in Smart contract?

Tags: blockchain, blocks, crowdsale, block-interval

I have seen contracts use block numbers to manage when the crowdsale should start and stop. How reliable is this? I understand the average time in ethereum is **17secs** between blocks, but can this be relied on as this can change in the future.

```
const startBlock = web3.eth.blockNumber + 2 // blockchain block number where the crowdsale will commence.

const endBlock = startBlock + 300  // 300 is little over an hour.
```

If this is avg 17 secs, can this be accurately use to give bonus slabs during the crowdsale? If not, what would be the best alternative?

Comment: Related: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10941/is-solidity-block-number-more-secure-than-timestamp

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of course. Both `block timestamp` and `block number` are equally reliable. There is an entire alarm clock system built in ethereum for executing something at a later stage. For more info on that you can even have a look at [How can a contract run itself at a later time?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/42/how-can-a-contract-run-itself-at-a-later-time/87#87)